# Firestore wrong order of documents

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore orders first by not mentioned field and then by the requested field

I am trying to order the documents (bookings) by the 'from' date of the booking with this query

```
query(this.colRef,orderBy("from","desc"));
```

Which ends up in this result:

[image: Result Image]

Randomly firestore first orders by the user and then by the 'from' date which is not as requested. The date is stored as timestamp in firestore.

[Firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPxSk.png)

Code how i display the result

```
<p-table [value]="bookings" dataKey="id"  [responsive]="true" [scrollable]="true" *ngIf="globals.windowWidth > 640">
<ng-template pTemplate="caption">
  <div class="table-header">
      <p-dropdown [options]="bookingYears" (onChange)="loadBookings()" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear" optionLabel="name"
                  optionValue="code" autoWidth="true" *ngIf="selectedYear!=undefined && !isShowingRequests"></p-dropdown>

      <button pButton pRipple type="button"  style="float: right;" icon="pi pi-refresh" (click)="loadBookings()" *ngIf="loadedBookings"></button>
      <button  icon="pi pi-spin pi-spinner" style="float: right;" class="p-button-rounded p-button-primary rightButton" pButton type="button" *ngIf="!loadedBookings"></button>
      <div></div>
      <br><br>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
  <tr>
      <th *ngIf="bookerID == undefined">Booker</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngIf="bookings.length == 0 && loadedBookings">
    <th colspan="6">
          No Bookings found!
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-booking >
  <tr>
      <td *ngIf="bookerID == undefined">
        {{booking.user.forename}} {{booking.user.lastname}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{booking.from.toLocaleDateString()}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{booking.to.toLocaleDateString()}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{bookingCalculationService.getTotalPrice(booking)}} €
      </td>
      <td >
        {{bookingsStatus[booking.status-1].name}}
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><!--pi-window-maximize-->
        <button (click)="showBookingInfoDialog(booking)" icon="pi pi-window-maximize" pButton pRipple type="button"   class="p-button-rounded p-button-outlined" title="Edit"></button><!---->
      </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

TS code

```
getDocs(query)
  .then((snapchot) => {
    let counter = 0;
    if(snapchot.docs.length ==0 )this.loadedBookings = true;

    snapchot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      this.fireStoreService.bookingConverter.fromFirestore(doc).then((booking: Booking) =>
      {
        if(this.isShowingRequests){
          if(this.authService.isLoggedInAndHost() && booking.status == 1)this.bookings.push(booking)
        }
        else if(this.isShowingBookingsAsHost){
          if(this.authService.isLoggedInAndHost() && booking.status != 1)this.bookings.push(booking)
        }
        else{
          if(this.authService.isLoggedIn())this.bookings.push(booking)
        }

        counter++;
        if(snapchot.docs.length == counter){
          this.loadedBookings = true;
        }
      });
    });
  })
  .catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e)
    this.showToastMessage('error', 'Error', 'An error orccured!');
  })
  ;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show: 1) a screenshot of one of the documents in the Firestore console. --- 2) the code how you display the results.

Comment: Please edit your post to show all the code as *text* rather than screenshots. That will make it much easier to help. (If you can reduce it to a minimal example rather than one with 10 different queries, that would also help a lot.)

Comment: also done - the query is the one mentioned at the top and the firestore document should be good enough as screenshot hopefully :)

Comment: Debugging step - Can you confirm if it's a server response or template at issue, either by inspecting the network tab or sticking `<pre>{{bookings | json}}</pre>` in the template

Comment: Its a server response issue i get them ordered as shown in the screenshot: first ordered by the user then ordered by the from date... also when debugging i get the response in this order from the server